# How to join multiple tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting the follow error "column ambiguously defined" from the input below.  I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

I am currently in school and this is one of my assignments. With this being said, I am very unexperienced and will most likely need a "child-like" explanation.  The assignment states, "Create a view to list all the movies available for renting. The view should include title, category description (not category_code), company, director, actor, store, copy, type."  I think I might be joining too many tables?!? Or, obviously, just not doing it correctly.  Any assistance will be tremendously appreciated.

```
create view AvailableMovies as
select m.title, mcat.description, comp.company_name, d.director_name, 
act.actor_name, mrs.store_name, mrl.available_for_rent, mrl.type_distributed
from companies comp
join directors d
on comp.company_id = d.company_id
join movie_directors mdir
on d.director_id = mdir.director_id
join actor_in_movies aim
on mdir.movie_id = aim.movie_id
join actors act
on aim.actor_id = act.actor_id
join actor_in_movies aim 
on act.actor_id = aim.actor_id
join order_items oi
on aim.movie_id = oi.movie_id
join orders o
on oi.order_id = o.order_id
join movie_rental_stores mrs
on o.store_id = mrs.store_id
join movie_rent_list mrl
on mrs.store_id = mrl.store_id
join movies m
on mrl.movie_id = m.movie_id
join movie_categories mcat
on m.category_code = mcat.category_code
order by m.title;
```

If this helps, below are ALL of the tables from my assignment:

```
create table companies(
company_id            number(3),
company_name          varchar2(30) not null,
description           varchar2(100)
);

create table movie_categories(
category_code         char(3) not null,
description           varchar2(50)
);

create table movies (
movie_id              number(5),
title                 varchar2(30) not null,
category_code         char(3) not null,
description           varchar2(500),
released_by           number(3) not null,
released_on           date not null
);

create table directors(
director_id       number(5),
director_name              varchar2(30) not null,
company_id        number(3) not null
);

create table movie_directors(
movie_director_id     number(5),
movie_id              number(5) not null,
director_id           number(5) not null
);

create table awards(
award_id              number(4),
award                 varchar2(30) not null,
award_description     varchar2(100)
);

create table movie_awards(
movie_award_id        number(5),
movie_id              number(5) not null,
award_id              number(4) not null,
award_date            date
);

create table actors(
actor_id            number(5),
actor_name          varchar2(30) not null,
gender              char(1),
contact             varchar2(20)
);

create table actor_in_movies(
movie_actor_id    number(5),
movie_id          number(5) not null,
actor_id          number(5) not null
);

create table movie_distributors(
distributor_id      number(3),
distributor_name    varchar2(30) not null,
location            varchar2(40),
contact             varchar2(40)
);

create table distributed_movie_list(
distribution_id           number(8),
movie_id                  number(5) not null,
distributor_id            number(3) not null,
distribute_type           varchar2(10),
inventory_quantity        number(3) default 0,
unit_price                number(8,2)
);

create table movie_rental_stores(
store_id                number(4),
store_name              varchar2(30) not null,
store_location          varchar2(50)
);

create table orders(
order_id                number(8),
store_id                number(4) not null,  
description             varchar2(30),
total_items             number(3),
total_payment           number(8,2),
tax                     number(6,2),
order_status            varchar2(2),
ordering_date           date,
order_completed_date    date
);

create table order_items(
item_id                   number(10),
order_id                  number(8) not null,
distribution_id           number(8) not null,
movie_id                  number(5) not null, 
number_of_items           number(3),
item_unit_price           number(5,2),
item_sub_total            number(10,2)
);


create table movie_rent_list(
title_id                     number(5),
movie_id                     number(5) not null,
store_id                     number(4) not null,
number_in_store              number(2),
available_for_rent           char(1),
rent_unit_price              number(5,2),
type_distributed             varchar2(10),        
overdue_unit_fee             number(5,2)
);

create table movie_copies(
copy_id               number(5),
title_id              number(5) not null,
available             char(1) default 'Y'
);

create table customers(
customer_id             number(5),
store_id                number(4) not null,
firstname               varchar2(20),
lastname                varchar2(20),
gender                  char(1),
address                 varchar2(50),
card_approved           char(1),
card_approved_date      date,
phone_number            varchar2(10),
card_number             number(10),
rent_limit              number(2),
overdue_notified        char(1)
);

create table movie_rent_records(
rent_record_id          number(8),
customer_id             number(5) not null,
copy_id                 number(5) not null,
rented_date             date,
returned_date           date, 
rent_fee                number(5,2),
overdue_fee             number(5,2),
overdue_days            number(2)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix the view.

The alias `aim` is being used twice.  Presumably this is causing the problem.

Comment: @ Gordon,  WOW!!! I worked on this for days. I had no idea this was causing the problem.  I changed the second aim to aim2 and now it worked perfect.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The error means the query's projection has a column which could come from more than one table.  You have been punctilious in aliasing your tables and using the aliases in your column references.  But, alas you include `actor_in_movies` in the FROM clause twice, and each time with the same alias, `aim`.

Hence the error: the database doesn't know which instance of `actor_in_movies` to use in the joins.

This looks like a cut'n'paste error to me.

Comment: @ APC, yes that was the error.  I thought aliases only mattered with subqueries.  After the easy fix, the view was created flawlessly. Thank you for your assistance!